jQuery Selectize.js with ajax data loading
I am trying to load data for jQuery plugin Selectize.js via ajax, but I am not able to delete options loaded with previous calls from dropdown element.
I am stuck with this code where I am able to load data via ajax and show them in dropdown, but I would like to delete them when dropdown is closed (because also typed text is deleted) and load a new ones from another ajax call (after new text is typed), but commands clearOptions(true) / refreshItems() does not delete anything. I would like to delete only items in dropdown. If any item is selected, it should stay so.
EDIT:
Based on the comments below I've updated sample code here. The current state is: items are properly loaded as options to dropdown, dropdown stays opened when data are loaded and typed text is not deleted after blur.
Only issue to solve (so far) is that when I type "something", data are loaded properly via ajax, then I select any option. It is just fine yet. But when I type "another", previous options from dropdown are deleted (that is correct), but also selected option is deleted (not correct). I understand why is that happened (selected options are deleted because options from dropmenu are deleted), but I do not have any idea how to solve it.
var selectize = $('#selectize').selectize({
  sortField: 'text',
  loadThrottle: 500,
  onFocus: function() {
    if (this.items[0] == '0') {
      this.clear();
    }
  },
  load: function(query, callback) {
    if (!query.length || query.length < 2) return callback();

    selectize[0].selectize.clearOptions();
    selectize[0].selectize.renderCache = {};

    var value = selectize[0].selectize.currentResults.query;
    var ajax = [{'value': '31', 'text': 'aaa yyy'}, {'value': '32', 'text': 'aaa xxx'}, {'value': '33', 'text': 'aaa zzz'}]; // simulation of loading data via ajax
    callback(ajax);

    // without those two lines I was not able to open dropdown menu after loading new options, IDKW
    selectize[0].selectize.blur();
    selectize[0].selectize.focus();

    // without this line I've lost typed text when loading new options to dropdown
    setTimeout(function() {
      selectize[0].selectize.setTextboxValue(value);
    }, 100);
  }
});


Try this way:
$('#selectize').selectize({
      valueField: 'value',
      labelField: 'text',
      searchField: 'text',
      persist: false,
      loadThrottle: 500,
      
      load: function(query, callback) {
        if (!query || query.length < 2) return callback();
        
        var self = this;
        var currentValue = query; 
        
        
        var selected = this.items;
        this.clearOptions();
        this.addOption(selected);
        
        $.ajax({
          url: 'api-endpoint',
          type: 'GET',
          data: { q: query },
          success: function(res) {
            callback(res);
            
            // Maintain dropdown state and input value
            setTimeout(function() {
              self.blur();
              self.focus();
              self.setTextboxValue(currentValue);
            }, 50);
          },
          error: function() {
            callback();
          }
        });
      },
    
      onBlur: function() {
        this.clearOptions(false);
      }
    });


Thanks, it looks like it should works, but now I have problem to open dropdown menu after callback() is called. I have to click outside of input and then click back to open dropdown with newly loaded options. Not even using this.open(); does not help. Any ideas how to solve it?

UPDATE: When I load data and then call this.blur() and this.focus(), then dropdown is opened, but I lost typed text from the input, so one problem is solved, but here is another.

@sylar32 Could you please edit your question and share the complete code so I can help more?

Sure, it is done, I've edited code and question above. The origin issues are solved, but another is discovered. When I load data more times, different queries, with different results, selected options are deleted.

@sylar32 I edited the answer, could you please try it now?

Unfortunatelly, it is still not it. Now the dropdown menu just blink when data are loaded, so nothing can not be selected. When I put out self.blur() and self.focus() out of setTimeout, dropdown menu stay opened, but when I select anything and jump out of input, selected values are deleted (I think, it is beucase onBlur: function(). And after that, when I make another query to load data, it is still not hold the previously selected options. I've made JSfiddle example - https://jsfiddle.net/9b3zpx0m/ - there are simulated data-sets to load, just type "aaa" or "bbb" to try it out.

ok so it is working or not now?

Unfortunatelly no, dropdown menu is not opened, it just blink when data are loaded and selected options are still deleted when new options are loaded by another query. Please see linked jsfiddle example and try type "aaa" or "bbb" as a query.

could you check if any other jquery/js used on the same page, that may be conflict?

I do not think it is caused by that, because the same behavior is on the JSfiddle example I mentioned above and there is no ohter JQ/JS included.
